# How to access SurfaceView from another class?

Tags: java, android, bitmap, surfaceview

[image: screenshot of game]

I am attempting to make a very simple shoot 'em up game where a ship can move left or right and fire bullets. I've gotten this far and realized I may have messed up in my placement of the objects and the type. The ship and buttons are currently ImageViews within a RelativeLayout. 
The star background is the only thing within my SurfaceView. It's not actually a "background," but a bitmap that is randomly generated, making it appear to move.

I am needing to create a few more objects: Bullets and Enemies. The main problem is that the bullets will need to access the ship coordinates so it appears to fire from the ship.

Have I gone about this wrong? Should I draw the buttons as Bitmaps onto the SurfaceView instead? I would like to know the best way to do this.

In its current state, the ship moves left to right seamlessly, and the buttons toggle color and cause the sound to play.

Here are my two classes:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.SoundPool;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    GameView gameView;
    FrameLayout game;
    RelativeLayout widgets;
    ImageButton leftButton;
    ImageButton rightButton;
    ImageButton leftFireButton;
    ImageButton rightFireButton;
    ImageView ship;
    float shipX;
    MediaPlayer mp;
    static final int leftButtonID = 1;
    static final int rightButtonID = 2;
    static final int leftFireButtonID = 3;
    static final int rightFireButtonID = 4;
    static final int laserId = 5;
    SoundPool soundPool;
    int soundID;
    //Bitmap laser;
    //ImageView laser;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ship = new ImageView(this);
        gameView = new GameView(this);
        game = new FrameLayout(this);
        widgets = new RelativeLayout(this);
        leftButton = new ImageButton(this);
        rightButton = new ImageButton(this);
        leftFireButton = new ImageButton(this);
        rightFireButton = new ImageButton(this);
        //laser = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.laser_beam);
        //laser = new ImageView(this);


        leftButton.setId(leftButtonID);
        rightButton.setId(rightButtonID);
        leftFireButton.setId(leftFireButtonID);
        rightFireButton.setId(rightFireButtonID);
        //laser.setId(laserId);


        //ship = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.spaceship_1_80x70); //should this be an image or bitmap?
        //laser.setImageResource(R.drawable.laser_beam); Should be a bitmap instead?
        leftButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.left_arrow);
        rightButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.right_arrow);
        leftFireButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_button);
        rightFireButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_button);
        ship.setImageResource(R.drawable.spaceship_1_80x70);


        //add views to screen
        game.addView(gameView);
        game.addView(widgets);
        widgets.addView(leftButton);
        widgets.addView(rightButton);
        widgets.addView(leftFireButton);
        widgets.addView(rightFireButton);
        widgets.addView(ship);
        leftButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        rightButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        leftFireButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        rightFireButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);


        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bass_loop);
        mp.setLooping(true);
        mp.start();
        loadSounds(this);


       leftButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
           private Handler handler;

           @Override
           public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
               switch(motionEvent.getAction()) {
                   case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                       if(handler != null) return true;
                       handler = new Handler();
                       handler.postDelayed(action,50);
                       break;
                       case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                           if(handler == null) return true;
                           handler.removeCallbacks(action);
                           handler = null;
                           break;
               }
               return true;
           }
           Runnable action = new Runnable() {
               @Override public void run() {
                   shipX = ship.getX() - 25;
                   ship.setX(shipX);
                   handler.postDelayed(this,50);
               }
           };
       });
        rightButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            private Handler handler;

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                switch(motionEvent.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        if(handler != null) return true;
                        handler = new Handler();
                        handler.postDelayed(action,50);
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        if(handler == null) return true;
                        handler.removeCallbacks(action);
                        handler = null;
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
            Runnable action = new Runnable() {
                @Override public void run() {
                    shipX = ship.getX() + 25;
                    ship.setX(shipX);
                    handler.postDelayed(this,50);
                }
            };
        });

        leftFireButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                switch(motionEvent.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                        //TODO FIRE BULLET....

                        leftFireButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_button_pressed);
                        soundPool.play(soundID,1.0f,0.5f,1,0,1.0f);
                        return true;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        leftFireButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_button);
                        //widgets.removeView(laser);
                        return true;
                }

                return false;
            }
        });
        rightFireButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                switch(motionEvent.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                        //TODO FIRE BULLET

                        rightFireButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_button_pressed);
                        soundPool.play(soundID,1.0f,0.5f,1,0,1.0f);
                        return true;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        rightFireButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_button);
                        //widgets.removeView(laser);

                        return true;
                }

                return false;
            }
        });

        //Setup ship
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams shipParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(250, 250);

        //Setup a 200 x 200 ImageView for Left Button
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams leftBtn = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(200,200);

        //Setup a 200 x 200 ImageView for Right Button
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rightBtn = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(200,200);

        //Setup a 200 x 200 ImageView for Left Fire Button
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams leftFireBtn = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(200,200);

        //Setup a 200 x 200 ImageView for Right Fire Button
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rightFireBtn = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(200,200);

        //Add rules to align the left button programmatically
        leftBtn.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
        leftBtn.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);

        //Add rules to align the right button programmatically
        rightBtn.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
        rightBtn.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);

        //Add rules to align left and right fire buttons
        leftFireBtn.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
        rightFireBtn.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
        leftFireBtn.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE,leftButton.getId());
        rightFireBtn.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, rightButton.getId());
        //leftFireBtn.topMargin = 850;
        //rightFireBtn.topMargin = 850;

        shipParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
        shipParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        //shipParams.bottomMargin = 100;

        //Now set the params
        leftButton.setLayoutParams(leftBtn);
        rightButton.setLayoutParams(rightBtn);
        leftFireButton.setLayoutParams(leftFireBtn);
        rightFireButton.setLayoutParams(rightFireBtn);
        ship.setLayoutParams(shipParams);

        //Set the content view of the game
        this.setContentView(game);
    }

    public void loadSounds(Context context) {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            soundPool = new SoundPool.Builder().setMaxStreams(10).build();
        }
        else {
            soundPool = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 1);
        }
        soundID = soundPool.load(context,R.raw.laser,1);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mp.pause();
        gameView.pause();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mp.start();
        gameView.resume();
    }
    public class GameView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {
        Thread gameViewThread = null;
        SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
        boolean okToRun = true;
        Bitmap star;
        Bitmap three_pixel_star;

        public GameView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            //initialize holder
            surfaceHolder = this.getHolder();
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(okToRun) {
                if(!surfaceHolder.getSurface().isValid()) {
                    continue;
                }
                Canvas gameCanvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
                customOnDraw(gameCanvas);
                surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(gameCanvas);

            }
        }

        protected void customOnDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            Random random = new Random();
            Random random1 = new Random();
            canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
            star = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.single_pixel_star);
            three_pixel_star = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.three_pixel_star);
            canvas.drawBitmap(star, random1.nextInt(canvas.getWidth()-star.getWidth()),random1.nextInt(canvas.getHeight()-star.getHeight()), null);
            canvas.drawBitmap(three_pixel_star, random.nextInt(canvas.getWidth()-three_pixel_star.getWidth()),random.nextInt(canvas.getHeight()-three_pixel_star.getHeight()), null);
        }
        public void pause() {
            okToRun = false;
            while(true) {
                try {
                    gameViewThread.join();
                } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                    Log.v("ERROR", e.getMessage());
                }
                break;
            }
            gameViewThread = null;
        }
        public void resume() {
            okToRun = true;
            gameViewThread = new Thread(this);
            gameViewThread.start();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I don't know if this is the "proper" way to do this *per se*, but I now have lasers shooting from my ship. I made a Bullet and BulletController class, and implemented a method in my onTouchListener.

Bullet class:

```
 public class Bullet {

    private float x;
    private float y;
    private Paint paint;

    Bitmap bullet;

    public Bullet(float x, float y, Context context) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;

        bullet = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.drawable.laser_beam);
    }
    public void tick() {
        y -= 30;
    }
    public void render(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(bullet, x, y,null);
    }
}
```

BulletController class:

```
 public class BulletController {

    private LinkedList<Bullet> b = new LinkedList<>();

    Bullet tempBullet;
    Context context;
    //ImageView ship;
    float x;
    float y;
    public BulletController(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        addBullet(new Bullet(x, y, context));
    }

    public void tick() {
        for(int i = 0; i < b.size(); i++) {
            tempBullet = b.get(i);
            tempBullet.tick();
        }
    }
    public void render(Canvas canvas) {
        for(int i = 0; i < b.size(); i++) {
            tempBullet = b.get(i);
            tempBullet.render(canvas);
        }
    }
    public void addBullet(Bullet bullet) {
        b.add(bullet);
    }
    public void removeBullet(Bullet bullet) {
        b.remove(bullet);
    }
}
```

In my setOnTouchListener for the two fire buttons:

```
 leftFireButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            switch(motionEvent.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    //TODO FIRE BULLET....
                    bulletController.addBullet(new Bullet((ship.getX() + ship.getWidth()/2) - 15, ship.getY() + ship.getHeight()/2, getApplicationContext())); //<--NEW CODE
                    leftFireButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_button_pressed);
                    soundPool.play(soundID,1.0f,0.5f,1,0,1.0f);
                    return true;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    leftFireButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_button);
                    //widgets.removeView(laser);
                    return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
    rightFireButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            switch(motionEvent.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    //TODO FIRE BULLET
                    bulletController.addBullet(new Bullet((ship.getX() + ship.getWidth()/2) - 15, ship.getY() + ship.getHeight()/2, getApplicationContext())); //<--- NEW CODE


                    rightFireButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_button_pressed);
                    soundPool.play(soundID,1.0f,0.5f,1,0,1.0f);
                    return true;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    rightFireButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_button);
                    //widgets.removeView(laser);

                    return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
```

With each button press, this is the end result. Lasers!

[image: pew pew]